# FileSystemWatcher unable to start

Tags: .net, windows, exception, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I am developing a Windows Service using C# 2010 and i am using the FileSystemWatcher.  For some reason, i am unable to start my service.

I get the following message when i try to run my service.

> The -service- on Local computer started and stopped.  Some services start automatically if they are not in use in other services or programs.

This occurs when i put this piece of code :

OnStart:

```
FSWatcherTest.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPath"].ToString();
```

and then in a method:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
     this.FSWatcherTest = new FileSystemWatcher();
     ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FSWatcherTest)).BeginInit();

       this.FSWatcherTest.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
       this.FSWatcherTest.Path = "my path";
       this.FSWatcherTest.Changed += new      FileSystemEventHandler(this.FSWatcherTest_Changed_1);
       ((ISupportInitialize)(this.FSWatcherTest)).EndInit();

}
```

Waiting for some possible answers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the service doing anything? just enabling a filesystemwatcher won't keep the service alive

Comment: @daveL: I doubt you're correct.

Comment: @Shaheel what's in your event log?

Comment: @daveL I have to copy files according to certain extension to another place. The copying is no problem. What i want is to monitor a particular folder and this is where the FileSystemWatcher comes into place. After putting this code, i cannot even start the service!

Comment: Please post the code of your OnStart() method so we can see what may be causing the trouble. For example, does it handle exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a security issue as the filesystemwatcher requires full trust

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this in a while so I may be off base, but you might be turning on the FileSystemWatcher before it's ready.

In the code above, EnableRaisingEvents is set to true in InitializeComponent (as part of designer generated code, I'm guessing).  The designer defaults that property to true expecting you to also set a valid path at design time.  But you're not setting a real path at design time (you're just using "my path").  The FSW may be throwing an exception right after EndInit() since it starts looking for "my path" and can't find it.

Since you're setting the real path in the OnStart method, you should have EnableRaisingEvents false in the designer.  Set it to true in the OnStart method after you set the path.  That's when you want it to start looking for changes.